# I am using laravel 5. I am using flash messaging, it is not working

Tags: php, laravel

My code like below!

**Controller:**

```
use Session;

    public function update($id, Request $request)
    {
    $book = Section::findOrFail($id);                     
    $input = $request->all();                                

       $book ->fill($input)->save();

                    Session::flash('message', 'Book successfully updated!');  
                    return redirect()->back();                      

        }
```

**And below is my Template file code :**

```
    @if(Session::has('message'))
       <div class="alert alert-primary fade in">
        <button data-dismiss="alert" class="close"><span>×</span></button>
                    {{ Session::get('message') }}
       </div>
    @endif
```

i am beginner for `laravel`. In controller i already use `Session` and then using `Session::flash('key','value')`, and in template file i get it using `Session::get()` method.

Comment: Are you using Laravel 5.2? If so, can you show your routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working by placing the route within the "web" middleware in route file:

```
Route::group(['middleware' =>['web'], 'prefix' => 'admin'], function () {   
    Route::resource('book', 'BookController');
});
```

After adding middleware web it works fine!

Comment: How come `middleware` responsible for not showing `Session` message?

Comment: That's why I asked about your routes.

Answer (score 0):

For a little more information: if you're on Laravel 5.2, this is most likely due to the `StartSession` middleware not being used by default.

If you take a look at `app/Http/Kernal.php`, you can see that two middleware groups are predefined: `web` and `api`. The `web` middleware group adds in the middleware for cookies, sessions, and the CSRF token.

If your route is not inside the `web` middleware group, then you do not get this functionality by default. If you place your route inside the `web` middleware group, your session should start working.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is probably that you have **2 web middlewares**. The second just kills flash data. I got it on fresh installation. You can try to check it by `$ php artisan route:list` command.

```
| | GET|HEAD | /  |   | App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@one | web,web |
```

So just remove `web` from `routes.php`

```
Route::group([], function () {    
 ....
```

Answer (score -1):

You got to import this class for the Session

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
```

Try that and it will work :-)

Comment: Did you trying removing "use Session" and add "use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;" in the controller  ?

Comment: please paste your routes.php

Answer (score -1):

In your controller try removing the session flash and replace the redirect line with

```
return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Book successfully updated!');
```